# AWS Cloudtrail: how does Cloudtrail logs look when instance state goes to "Terminating:Wait" state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling, amazon-cloudtrail

As you can see in this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks-overview.html

instances in AWS can go to "Terminating:Wait" state. My question is how cloudtrail log show look when an instance goes from "running" to "Terminating:Wait"?

Comment: Are you trying to create an EventBridge rule?

Comment: @Paolo no. I'm just trying to see how logs look in these cases.